# Using recursion to generate all substrings of a given string

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

I should start off by saying there are similar questions asked here but for the assignment i am on i cannot use any loops and all the answers to these questions use loops. So Use java 6 and recursion to generate all the substrings of a given string. For example your given String word = "Ralph"; i need the output to be formatted like this.

```
Ralph
Ralp
Ral
Ra
R
alph
alp
al
a
lph
lp
l
ph
h
```

Here's my generate method

```
    //written by Justin Tew<BR>

public static void generate(String word) 
{


    //base case... wtf is the base case here?
    //idk bout this 
    if (word.length() == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(word);
        return;
    }


    //recursive case
    if (word.length() != 0)
    {

        System.out.println(word);
        generate(word.substring(0, word.length()-1)); //gets the first 5 substrings
    }
```

output:

```
Ralph
Ralp
Ral
ra
r
```

In my mind this call, `generate(word.substring(1, word.length()-1));` should get the next 5 but it doesn't it gets very weird output...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Both the 2 answers were pretty much right. I just added a new method called `suffixGen`:

```
public static void suffixGen(String word)
{
    if (word.length() > 1)
    {
        generate(word);
        suffixGen(word.substring(1));
    }

}
```

and in my main I just call `suffixGen` instead of `generate` and it gets me the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recursing on the letters of the word, you could recurse on the word length. For example, on the top level of recursion you could find all substrings with `word.length()` letters then `word.length() - 1` letters and so on. This would probably require two recursive methods though, one to loop through the word lengths and one to loop through all possible substrings of that length.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have done most of the work already. Just write another recursive method `generateSuffix(word)` which

- first calls `generate(word)`
- then calls `generateSuffix()` with the longest suffix of word.

You will still need a similar base case to what you have in generate.

Comment: makes since gonna try it after school today ty

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
String word; 
int word_length = word.length(); //get the length of the word

for(int i=0;i<word_length;i++){
   for(int j=0; j<=word_length-i ; j++){

       String sub = word.substring(i,i+j); 
       System.out.println(sub); //print the substrings
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to read solution here

```
public class AllSubStrings {
    //hashset to keep a record of all the substrings
    static HashSet<String> subStrings_r=new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString="Sujal";
        getSubstrings_r(testString);
        System.out.println("RECURSION ->"+subStrings_r);
    }

    public static void getSubstrings_r(String testString){
        _getSubstrings_r(testString, 0, testString.length());
    }

    public static void _getSubstrings_r(String testString,int start,int end){
        if(start==end){ //base condition
            return;
        }
        subStrings_r.add(testString.substring(start, end));
        //start getting substrings from left to right
        _getSubstrings_r(testString,start+1,end); 
        //start getting substrings from right to left
        _getSubstrings_r(testString,start,end-1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers work, but you can do it without helper methods or changing the method signature, as long as you're ok with duplicates. Just use multiple recursive calls.

```
public static void generate(String word){
    System.out.println(word);
    if(word.length() <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    generate(word.substring(1);
    generate(word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a helper method, if you pass an additional string to the method, just pass it's value as a blank as shown in the method call below:

```
    public static void substrings(String str, String temp)
    {
        if(str.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.println(temp); return;
        }

          substrings(str.substring(1), temp+str.substring(0,1));
          substrings(str.substring(1), temp);
    }
```

A sample call --->**substrings("abc", "")**;

produces the output below:

abc

ab

ac

a

bc

b

c

There is one invisible string which is actually a blank string.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. `ac` isn't a substring of `abc`.