# Get all treepaths of a Tree as String

Tags: java, recursion, tree, traversal, subtree

I'm searching now a while for a method, which gave me all path of a given tree. Imagine the following Tree:

```
A
  B
  C
    D
      E
    F
  G
```

Now I want to get all path as separate String:

- AB
- ACDE
- ACF
- AG

---------------Update-----------------

As already mention in the comments, I'm looking for all treepaths rather than subtrees.
I found the following solution, but I'm unsure if it's gonna be a good one:

```
  private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> abstractProperties;

    ........

    getTreePath(abstractHw, new ArrayList<String>());

.......

    private void getTreePath(Node hw, ArrayList<String> path) {
        path.add(hw.getName());
        if (hw.getNodes().isEmpty()) {
            abstractProperties.add(path);
        } else {
               for (Node subHw : hw.Nodes()) {
                getTreePath(subHw, new ArrayList<String>(path));
               }
            }
    }
```

What do you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using recursion to generate all substrings of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197696/using-recursion-to-generate-all-substrings-of-a-given-string)

Comment: @ZongZhengLi that's really not a duplicate. ph09: what representation do you have for the tree?

Comment: No, not a duplicate of that question at all.

Comment: @Cruncher Yep, not anymore (after hyde's edit). Initially, the "tree" was given as "A B C D E F G".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "subtree"?  From your example, it looks like you mean every path from the root to a leaf.  If this is what you mean, then this is just the same as traversing through all the leaf nodes (in whichever order makes sense), and outputting the full path to that leaf.  If that's not what you intend, please clarify the question.

Comment: In Your recursion, You simply need to pass the start of string in recursion call.

Comment: What do you mean with representation? The underlying technology is EMF for creating the tree. For example to get the childs of A, there is a method A.getChilds which is returning a List of B,C,G

Comment: ...(cont) and then print the string when you get to leaf.

Comment: see edit of my question

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BFS algorithm (a graph algorithm explained on Wikipedia), starting from the node you want to make root.

The algorithm behaves like this:

```
procedure BFS(G,v,btree):
      create a queue Q
      enqueue v onto Q
      mark v
      btree = new Tree(v);//Create a tree structure with v as root
      while Q is not empty:
          t ← Q.dequeue()
          btree.add(t) // Here its where you add elements to your tree
          for all edges e in G.incidentEdges(t) do
             o ← G.opposite(t,e)
             if o is not marked:
                  mark o
                  enqueue o onto Q
```

When Q is empty means you processed all the possible nodes and all of them have been added to your binary tree (btree).

Once you have your btree you can apply any simple algorithm to obtain what you need

Comment: Personally, if you are not searching for something as shallow as possible, I would use DFS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: I don't have a binary tree, so I think this doesn't work for me

Comment: btree isn't short for binary tree, though I would prefer Btree.

Answer (score 0):

You implementation of the tree (or more accurately the nodes) need to be able to return whether or not they have children.

If you want a more detailed answer show what you have tried and show us how you are storing your tree.

Comment: I provided a code example..Maybe you can tell me what you think of it

Comment: @ph09 is Node your own class or from a java package?

Comment: It's my class..just as an example

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to print the full paths to the leaf nodes in an arbitrary tree structure:

```
<script>
    function factory(name, children) {
        return {
            name: name,
            children: children
        }
    }

    var paths = [];

    function getGroupPaths(node, path) {
        path.push(node.name);
        if (node.children.length == 0) {
            console.log(path.join());
        } else {
            for (child of node.children) {
                getGroupPaths(child, path);
            }
        }
        path.pop();
    }

    var acca = factory('acca', []);
    var accb = factory('accb', []);
    var accc = factory('accc', []);
    var aca = factory('aca', []);
    var acb = factory('acb', []);
    var acc = factory('acc', [acca, accb, accc]);
    var aa = factory('aa', []);
    var ab = factory('ab', []);
    var ac = factory('ac', [aca, acb, acc]);
    var ad = factory('ad', []);
    var a = factory('a', [aa, ab, ac, ad]);

    var path = [];
    getGroupPaths(a, path);
</script>
```

And the result:

a,aa

a,ab

a,ac,aca

a,ac,acb

a,ac,acc,acca

a,ac,acc,accb

a,ac,acc,accc

a,ad