# Substring Recursion from text file Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, arraylist, substring

So for this program we are to use recursion. We have to import a text file containing five words and then for those words we have to find all possible substrings and store them in an array list. So, if the word was cards: cards card car ca c ards ard ar a rds rd r ds d s.

The instructions are that we must create a static method that returns an ArrayList of type String that takes only a single parameter, a String.

So in order for something to be recursive, it must call itself in order to simplify things, and there must be an action for the base case. So for now I have:

```
public static ArrayList<String> SubstringCalculator (String theName)
{
   /* Do I call create a new ArrayList here? Wouldn't that mean
    * that every time I call this method an entire new ArrayList
    * is created? I only want one ArrayList.
    */
   ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
   System.out.print (theString);
   result.add(theString)   // Add the string to the ArrayList
   if (theString.length > 1) {
      // Make a new string with 1 char less than the original.
      String newString = theString.substring(0, theString.length() - 1);
      // Call the method again with the new string.
      SubstringCalculator (newString);
      return result;
   }
   return theString;   // Return the string if it is of length 1.
}
```

I know this is not right, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any help?

Comment: Studying the same course as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197696/using-recursion-to-generate-all-substrings-of-a-given-string?rq=1)?

Comment: Looks like a similar problem, though the directions on mine seem different. We are allowed to use loops on this one (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: theName is theString ??? typing error ???

Comment: Yes, it should read theName, Typing error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch.  If the string is empty, return an list containing an empty string.  If not, you have two strings: first (the first character in a string) and the rest of the string.  Find all substrings of the rest of the string, then for each of these, put the first character in all possible positions.

Comment: The part that confuses me is "return a string." The method is supposed to return an ArrayList<String> so how am I supposed to return a string if I am to return an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

If your string has length of 1, you should return the list with the string itself. If the string has length which is bigger than 1:

- initilize a new list A
- take out the first or last character from the string and call the method on the new substring, this will return a list B ( this is recursive)
- add all elements of B to A
- iterate through B append the first or last character to first or last position to each of string in B then add to A.
- return A.

Comment: If the method is supposed to return an ArrayList<String>, can I return just a string then?

Comment: If you want to return the string from the method, then I guess you can declare A as a static field and work on A only (no need the immediate list B any more)

Answer (score 0):

Another shot:

1. You have function with string input
2. Create an empty ArrayList
3. Add your input to the ArrayList
4. If your input is just one character long, return the ArrayList
5. Remove first letter from input
6. Call self with string from #5. as input, save the returned ArrayList
7. Remove last letter from input
8. Call self with string from #7. as input, save the returned ArrayList
9. Iterate over both results from #6 and #8.

   1. Check if that string is already in the ArrayList from #2.
   2. If not, add it
10. Return ArrayList from #2.
11. Profit

But I still can't figure out, how to optimize out 9 ...